# SAPUI5 : Cannot access the View during Routing in init

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am having a problem with the routing. Navigation is successful to a `childview` like *`oRouter.navTo('child')`* .... but when the application goes to the child's controller ... well I cannot access child's View in the init function.

[debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQM4m.png)

*`this.getView()`* fails as it does not have it ...perhaps loaded yet? in the console when I debug it does not exist... **`Uncaught TypeError: this.getView is not a function`**

but if I use console.log to write it I can see that it's there?!:

[with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMfUz.png)

I don't understand what's happening here as I also have another navigation to another, different view and it works there perfectly.

I tried setting the routing to async: false but it did not help...

Manifest snippet:

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": false,
            "viewPath": "namespace.view",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "controlId": "myApp",
            "clearControlAggregation": false
"routes": [{
            "name": "TargetMain",
            "pattern": "",
            "target": "TargetMain"
        }, {
            "name": "toEmpty",
            "pattern": "child1",
            "target": "toEmpty"
        }, {
            "name": "child2",
            "pattern": "child2",
            "target": "child2"
        }, {
            "name": "toError",
            "pattern": "child3",
            "target": "child3"
        }, 
        }],
"targets": {
            "TargetMain": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "page",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "Main",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Who is calling the **init** method?
You can use the onInit method ..its called once the view elements are initialized

Comment: In my understanding it should be called when the router's navTo method is triggered. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: to be honest i have never added init method in a view controller.
I just tried replicating the scenario but my  debugger would not go inside the init method on navigation

Answer (score 0):

When you call navTo on the router, it will

1. match the patterns according to your config
2. find corresponding target (may be more than one)
3. in each target, a view is listed
4. if that view is not loaded yet, it will load the view
5. Duting loading of the view, the view also loads its own controller (controller is specified in the view)
6. During initialisation, onInit in the controller is called
7. after inisialisation, the event "route matched" is fired

Two things to be observed: the controller is loaded by the view, so `this.getView()` is always available.

what you see in the screenshot of the debugger, may well be a `Component`, rather than a `Controller`. You can find out by calling `this.getMetadata()`. A controller has no private member `oModels`. A component has such a private member. A component has an `init` method, which is called when the component is initialised. A controller has an `onInit` method.

Now why a component is loaded, I can't tell from screenshts. Maybe one of your views that are loaded by the router contains a `ComponentContainer` which, in turn, loads a Component and calls the `ìnit` method of the component.

The component has no view, and no `getView` method.